# watch-video.net malware and preventing these types of infections at the network level

Tags: malware, windows-10, detection

How does a computer get infected with `watch-video.net` malware, and why aren't popular tools like windows defender or malwarebytes able to detect and remove it? Is there a practical way to prevent these types of things at the network level?

When i do a search online the only results that I see are from what look like bot sites designed to show you a solution to an expected search term and promote some software.

[image]

Comment: I think you interpreting the message wrong. It is not that your system is actually infected. Instead some site you visit in the browser __claims__ that your system is infected, in order to lure you into downloading some software (which then might infect your system) or buy something or similar. This is a type of phishing also called scareware.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, is that pop up actually just a google chrome "Notification" from a site?

Comment: Yes, this looks like a notification from Chrome to me. But I'm not completely sure since I see only the images without any context.

Comment: When I looked at his chrome settings for allowed notifications, it was for trusted sites (wrike and google docs) and there were no sites in the blocked notification list. So i wasn't able to confirm where the notification was coming from. To resolve the issue, I cleared all his browsing history and cookies. But we don't know where the notification was being triggered from.

Comment: I'm closing this because I think it is based on a faulty assumption and you are not even sure what's going on. Until you know what the infection actually is (or if there is any) there's not much for us to say.

Comment: @schroeder, I'm not a security researcher so posting it here seems like the most appropriate place. I might have a faulty assumption but at least provide ways to validate something like this. As you can see from the comments, i did basics as a result of seeing "Google Chrome" but don't know how else to validate. So a valid answer could be Steffen comment about it possibly being scareware and how to validate that.